# Simplify $\frac{1}{x-2}-\frac{1}{x+2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Simplify:

$$\frac{1}{x-2}-\frac{1}{x+2}$$

What I did was multiply both sides to get the denominator equal:

$$\frac{x+2}{(x-2)(x+2)}-\frac{x-2}{(x-2)(x+2)}=\frac{x^2+4x+4}{x^2-4} =\frac{4x+4}{ -4}=\frac{4 (x+1)}{-1}$$

Apparently this is not correct. Can anyone show me what I did wrong in steps?

Comment: Could you give reasons justifying the second line?

Comment: I multiplied both 1's diagonally.

Comment: The step after that i meant: where is $x^2+4x+4$ coming from in the numerator

Comment: @user160137 I have typeset your equations into LaTeX. Please double-check that I transcribed correctly.

Comment: x^2 + 4x + 4 I got from x-2 - (x+2). I thought this meant to be multiplied. Ithought this was x times x = x^2. 2x + 2x = 4x and the final 2*2=4. But I see that was wrong also. I already got my answer thanks.

Comment: There are some as would say that it’s already simplified.

Comment: The answer in the book Essential Mathematics for Economic Analysis  showed 4/ x^2 -4. I now understand how I get there and what I did wrong.

Comment: Thanks Neil, yes that looks better and is correct. Perhaps this is not the place but how do I type in LaTeX?

Comment: I agree with Lubin, there is really no such thing as a simplified expression, there is only the right form for the task at hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{1}{x-2}-\frac{1}{x+2} = \frac{x+2}{(x-2)(x+2)}- \frac{x-2}{(x+2)(x-2)} = \frac{x+2 - (x-2)}{(x+2)(x-2)} = \frac{x+2 - x + 2 }{(x+2)(x-2)} = \frac{4}{(x+2)(x-2)} = \frac{4}{x^2-4}$.

First step is getting common denominator, second step is combining fractions with common denominator, third step is distributing the $-$, 4th step is combining like terms and the final step is expanding out the denominator using difference of squares.

Comment: I see it now. I multiplied instead of combining like terms. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{x+2}{(x-2)(x+2)}-\frac{x-2}{(x-2)(x+2)} $$
$$ = \frac{x+2 - (x-2)}{(x-2)(x+2)} $$
$$= \frac{x+2 - x+2}{(x-2)(x+2)}$$
$$ = \frac{x - x+2 +2}{(x-2)(x+2)} $$
$$ = \frac{4}{(x-2)(x+2)}$$